# continue-on-error: true makes workflow invalid

Tags: github, github-actions

I am reading [the following](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontinue-on-error):

> #### `jobs.<job_id>.continue-on-error`
>
> Prevents a workflow run from failing when a job fails. Set to `true`
> to allow a workflow run to pass when this job fails.

However, I have this:

[image]

It seems to me it does not work, or linter does not work.

Any clue?

Comment: I have found that if I had the continue-on-error in the dispatched workflow, then it will work, but that's a bit annoying... is there another way ?